# Private function member called outside of class

Tags: c++, c++11

In the example below, why is `B::f()` called even though it is private?

I know this fact that :
Access is checked at the call point using the type of the expression used to denote the object for which the member function is called.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  virtual void f() { std::cout << "virtual_function"; }
};

class B : public A {
private:
  void f() { std::cout << "private_function"; }
};

void C(A &g) { g.f(); }

int main() {
  B b;
  C(b);
}
```

Comment: Because it is public in A, presumably and due to the fact that A is a parent and you are using it from an A object it doesn't bother checking the scope on the child, it is just overridden by the fact that it is public in A. Just my thoughts.

Comment: What you've stated explains it - the static type of `g` in `C` is `A&`, and `f()` is a public member function of `A`. That's all access control cares about. Change `C()`'s parameter type to `B&` and your code will fail to compile.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because the standard says so:

> `[C++11: 11.5/1]:` The access rules (Clause 11) for a virtual function are determined by its declaration and are not affected by the rules for a function that later overrides it. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> class B {
> public:
>   virtual int f();
> };
> class D : public B {
> private:
>   int f();
> };
> void f() {
>   D d;
>   B* pb = &d;
>   D* pd = &d;
>   pb->f();       // OK: B::f() is public,
>                  // D::f() is invoked
>   pd->f();       // error: D::f() is private
> }
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

The example is the same as yours, lol.

Answer (score 6):

`private` functions can override `public` virtual functions from a base class.  Accessability is, in a fact, completely ignored when determining whether a function overrides another, so even in

```
// Redundant private for clarity:
class A { private: virtual void foo(); };
class B : A { public: void foo(); };
```

`B::foo` overrides `A::foo`.

Comment: This example isn't very interesting, given that `B` declares `foo` private just like `A` did, _and_ it inherits privately.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Adjusted.

Comment: It's still got private inheritance. Is that deliberate? If so, consider adding `private` in there, too?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, it is deliberate. The crucial fact is that the foo in `B` is `public` and the foo in `A` is `private`. Actually it is completely irrelevant in what way I derive because `A::foo` ends up being inaccessible anyway.

Answer (score 4):

During **compile time** C++ compiler verifies accessibility of functions and methods based on their type. In function C variable g is of type A (checked during compilation of the code), in which method f is declared as public.

Take a look at [this link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-happens-when-more-restrictive-access-is-given-in-a-derived-class-method-in-c/)