# Public virtual method overridden as private. Generalization/specialization/Liskov principles violation?

Tags: c++, oop, solid-principles, design-principles

As in [Private function member called outside of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097578/private-function-member-called-outside-of-class), one can write the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  virtual void f() { std::cout << "A::f()"; }
};

class B : public A {
private:
  void f() override { std::cout << "B::f()"; }
};

void g(A &g) { g.f(); }

int main() {
  A a;
  g(a);
  a.f();
  B b;
  g(b);
  b.f(); // compilation failure
}
```

Of course, the compiler refuses to compile the last line, because the static analysis of the code reveals that `B::f()` is defined but private.

What seriously troubles me is the relation with the conceptual generalization/specialization. It is generally considered that you must be able to manipulate an instance of a subtype at least the same way you manipulate an instance of the super type.

This is the basis of the [Liskov's substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). In the given example, that is respected when `g()` is called either with an argument of type `A` or one of type `B`. But the last line is not accepted, and it seems that in such a case the substitution principle is violated in some way (consider a call-by-name as in a macro-definition `#define h(x) (x.f())`).

Even if one may consider that the Liskov's principle is not violated (macros are not real part of the language, so ok), the fact that the last line gives a compile-time error, at least means that objects of type `B` can't be manipulated as `A`'s can be. So that `B` is not a specialization of `A` even if the derivation is `public`.

Thus in C++, using a `public` derivation does not guarantee that you are effectively implementing a specialization. You need to consider more properties of the code to be sure that you have a ‘‘correct’’ specialization.

Am I wrong ? Is someone able to give me a justification for it ? I would like a good semantic argument, I mean at least something much more elaborate than Stroustrup's ones like ‘‘C++ tries not to constrains you, you are free to use it if you want and not if you don't want’’. I think that a language need to be founded on a reasonable model, not on a huge list of possible tricks.

Comment: I don't understand how you can override a public virtual method with a private one.

Comment: This is possible in C++, so the question is not ‘‘how?’’ but why is this possible?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that, according to the C++ standard, accessibility is simply not part of a member function signature.  That's answers as to why this is allowed.  I'm not sure I can answer whether the standard *should* allow it, though.

Comment: Ok but this is a technical argument. But I want to know why, because it is very weird...

Comment: I just explained why.  Overriding works by signature and accessibility doesn't change the function signature.

Comment: No, you explained how it works (I know how), not why is this possible ? Why C++ designers allowed it as it is mostly a non-sense (to me) ? It is strictly forbidden in every other OOP language I know.

Comment: I'm not sure why it was designed this way.  It's worth noting that it's kind of misleading to call C++ an OOP language.  It's a multi-paradigm language so it's not 100% designed under the OOP paradigm.  Also, I suppose I can think of one use case for it.  You want to provide an implementation of 'f' inside of 'B' but you don't want anyone who knows they have a 'B' to directly call it.  You want to force them to always call it via the base class handle, for whatever reason.  Obviously, using NVI would be a better way to approach this.

Comment: Ok, you mean by the use of a factory, but if you don't want others to know that `B` exists, then there is no need to protect anything in it.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a great example.  Maybe we need to get Stroustrup on here to answer for this :)